# rtweet package in R, finding the tweet location and user location

Tags: r, rtweet

I am collecting some tweets using `rtweet` package in **R** using below chunk of codes:

```
df <- search_tweets(
  "#some_random_tweets",
  n = 10,
  type = "mixed"
)
```

It returns several columns from which the location can be extracted such as `df$location`, `df$place_full_name`, `df$country`, `df$retweet_location`, etc.

Does anyone know how to distinguish between the tweet location (*when user shares location at time of Tweet*) and the user location (*home location provided by user in their public profile*); which one returns the tweet location and which one returns the user location?

Does it store the latitude and longitude information as well?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Perhaps relevant: https://rud.is/books/21-recipes/geocoding-locations-from-profiles-or-elsewhere.html

Comment: Thank you!
This is what I was looking for.